# Возможно ли в unix создать файловый дескриптор, не создавай и не открывая файл с помощью open?

Tags: c, unix

Возможно ли в unix создать файловый дескриптор, не создавая сам файл?

У меня возникла идея, реализовать пул thred'ов c помощью epoll. Т.е для каждого thred'а создается свой файловый дескриптор, и когда thred свободен, писать что нибудь в файловый дескриптор. Epoll бы это отлавливал, и при вызове epoll_wait возвращал бы список дескрипторов тех thred'ов, которые не заняты рабртой. Я знаю, что есть fork, но для выполнения задачи требуется одно адресное пространство. 
Или если это невозможно, как в процесс, созданный с помощью fork передать дескриптор сокета(если дексриптор был открыт после содания процесса)

Comment: [man pipe](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pipe.2.html)

Comment: Пишется так: `thread`.

Answer (score 1):

> Т.е для каждого thred'а создается свой файловый дескриптор, и когда thred свободен, писать что нибудь в файловый дескриптор. Epoll бы это отлавливал, и при вызове epoll_wait возвращал бы список дескрипторов тех thred'ов, которые не заняты рабртой.

Классическое решение — использовать трубы ([`man 2 pipe`](http://ru.manpages.org/pipe/2)) или сигналы (второе относительно сложно и надо быть аккуратным).

Linux-специфичный вариант для использования вместо трубы для уведомления только о событиях — [`eventfd`](http://ru.manpages.org/eventfd/2).

Для дуплексного общения между двумя потоками вместо трубы можно также использовать [`socketpair`](http://ru.manpages.org/socketpair/2).

Comment: Я знаю, что 2 процесса можно связать с помощью pipe, меня интересует, как дублировать открытый дескриптор сокета из одного процесса в другой, если на момент создания дескриптора соккета, второй процесс уже запущен

Comment: @DenverToha, если кратко — ни как... нужно сначала открыть сокет, а уже потом выполнять `fork()`... но я не особо понимаю, что ты тут вообще хочешь делать с помощью `fork()`...

Comment: @DenverToha, открытый дескриптор из одного процесса в другой (независимый) передают вызовом [sendmsg](https://linux.die.net/man/2/sendmsg) (детали гуглите со словами `unix magic`)

Comment: @avp, ?? как? о_О

Comment: @Fat-Zer, какой-то добрый человек [тут много написал](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28005250/7286264)

Comment: @avp... мда уж... не ожидал, что такое есть... тем более в стандартном варианте...

Comment: @Fat-Zer, да, интересная штука (изобретательные люди ведь ее придумали), насколько понимаю, делается что-то вроде dup2 в чужой процесс

Comment: @avp, спасибо большое, похоже это то, что мне было нужно